# ¿Utilizar variables o array directamente con extract en PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código de PHP:

```
$data = [
    "nombre" => "Persona",
    "edad" => 25
];
```

Pretendo renderizar un archivo de tal modo que al utilizar `extract($data)` se crean dos variables para `$nombre` y `$edad`, viéndose de esta forma:

```php
<p><b>Nombre:</b> <?php echo $nombre; ?></p>
<p><b>Edad:</b> <?php echo $edad; ?></p>
```

Sin embargo, también es posible pasar a la vista el diccionario directamente:

```php
<p><b>Nombre:</b> <?php echo $data["nombre"]; ?></p>
<p><b>Edad:</b> <?php echo $data["edad"] ?></p>
```

Lo que desconozco, y es mi pregunta, ¿cuál es el método más óptimo en todos los aspectos, especialmente para el rendimiento? Por ejemplo, ¿el hecho de utilizar `extract` puede suponer un uso de memoria extra para crear una variable o es preferible un diccionario?

Comment: Si la pregunta es explicitamente por el rendimiento, usar `extract` no otorga ningún beneficio, por el contrario, crear nuevas variable require mas memoria e incrementa la probabildad de sobre escribir variables. Si la pregunta se inclina a "mejores practicas" (mi opinion) deberías tipar los datos o programar orientado a objetos, es decir, la "vista" debería recibir un tipo de dato, por ejemplo, una instacia de la clase `Persona`; es facil de debugear, tenes autocompletado, etc.

Answer (score 1):

no sé si he entendido bien tu pregunta pero me gustaría intentar aclararte:

La claridad del código, la facilidad de mantenimiento y el rendimiento son algunos de los factores que determinan si usar "extract($data)" o acceder directamente a los elementos del array "$data" en su vista.

**Usando "extract($data)":**

*Ventajas*

1. Sintaxis más sencilla: permite acceder directamente a las variables sin referenciar el array.
2. Facilita la lectura: mejora la limpieza y la facilidad de lectura del código, especialmente en vistas con muchas variables.

*Desventajas*

1. Posibles riesgos de colisión de nombres: Si hay claves en el array que coinciden con nombres de variables existentes, podrían sobrescribirse accidentalmente.
2. La fuente de los datos no está completamente clara: De dónde provienen las variables, puede ser menos evidente para otros desarrolladores o para usted en el futuro.

**Acceso directo a los elementos de la tabla**

*Ventajas*

1. No hay peligro de que se confundan los nombres: Dado que accede directamente a los elementos del array, no es posible sobrescribir variables existentes.
2. Más información sobre la fuente de datos: De dónde provienen las variables puede ser más evidente.

*Desventajas*

1. La sintaxis más larga puede hacer que el código sea más extenso y menos sencillo.
2. Puede hacer que tu vista sea más densa y difícil de leer, especialmente si hay muchas variables.

**Consideraciones de rendimiento**

En la mayoría de los casos, la diferencia entre ambas opciones suele ser mínima en términos de rendimiento. En general, las preferencias de estilo y la legibilidad del código determinan la elección entre ellas. Sin embargo, es posible que quieras evitar el uso de extracto en casos donde la memoria es un recurso crítico, ya que puede crear variables adicionales en el ámbito actual.

En conclusión, ambos métodos son válidos, y elegir uno depende de sus preferencias personales y de las necesidades específicas de su código y proyecto. Siempre es recomendable optimizar para la claridad y la facilidad de mantenimiento antes de preocuparse demasiado por cambios mínimos en el rendimiento.

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que hablas de *renderizar* al plantear la pregunta. Realmente no necesitas crear variables por cada valor, si de eso se trata.

Puedes trabajar con algo parecido a una plantilla, y extraer los valores leyendo el array en un bucle, que suele ser la forma más óptima, aunque esto dependerá siempre del contexto y en cada caso, para decidir lo más óptimo debes hacer pruebas del tipo benchmark.

Aplicando lo dicho, tu código quedaría así:

```
$data = [
    "nombre" => "Persona",
    "edad" => 25
];
$template='<p><b>%s:</b>%s</p>';
foreach ($data as $k=>$v){
    printf($template,ucfirst($k),$v);
}
```

**Salida:**

```
<p><b>Nombre:</b>Persona</p><p><b>Edad:</b>25</p>
```

Si no quieres imprimir in situ, porque vas a concatenar más cosas en tu salida, simplemente cambia `printf` por `sprintf`.

```
$data = [
    "nombre" => "Persona",
    "edad" => 25
];
$template='<p><b>%s:</b>%s</p>';
#Variable para concatenar
$html="";
foreach ($data as $k=>$v){
    $html.=sprintf($template,ucfirst($k),$v);
}
#Usar $html a posteriori
```

### La mejor de las opciones

Es pasar a una implementación orientada a objetos, como sugiere @Marcos en su comentario.

Al modelar tu objeto, podrías dotarlo de aquellos métodos que requieras para la aplicación. Veamos un ejemplo de una clase `Person`, con un método `renderHtml` que te renderiza las propiedades de esa clase con un formato HTML. Esto se puede extender, y hacer que tu clase renderice también en Json, en XML, etc, según las necesidades e implementando otras interfaces del lenguaje.

La clase, en una versión muy simplificada, sería esta:

```
class Person
{
    private string $firstName;
    private string $lastName;
    private int $age;
    public function __construct(string $firstName,string $lastName,int $age)
    {
        $this->firstName=$firstName;
        $this->lastName=$lastName;
        $this->age=$age;
    }
    
    public function renderHtml(){
        $html="";
        $template="<p><b>%s:</b> %s</p>";
        foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $k=>$v) {
            $html.=sprintf($template,ucfirst($k),$v);
        }
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Ahora, donde recoges los datos, en vez de una array, creas una instancia de `Person`:

```
$unaPersona=new Person("Pedro","Serrano",25);
```

Y para mostrar los datos en formato HTML, sólo tienes que llamar al método `renderHtml` de la instancia de `Person` que acabas de llenar.

```
echo $unaPersona->renderHtml();
```

**Salida:**

```
<p><b>FirstName:</b> Pedro</p>
<p><b>LastName:</b> Serrano</p>
<p><b>Age:</b> 25</p>
```

---

[<kbd>`VER FIDDLE.`</kbd>](https://3v4l.org/sG7FP)

---

Los nombres de las propiedades salen en inglés, porque es preferible usar una convención de nombre en inglés. Para salidas en distintos idiomas, puedes usar la extensión de internacionalización, y/o implementar código para salidas en varios idiomas. Todo esto, que es un tema muy amplio, se resolvería con un par de líneas de código si usas la programación orientada a objetos, mientras que con otro tipo de programación, supondría algo así como tener que escribir la misma aplicación para cada idioma.

Comment: Aunque de esta forma (encapsulando la presentación) renuncias a MVC y a la [*separación de intereses*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separación_de_intereses). Para tu ejemplo podría sonar mejor una clase *PersonRenderer* que implemente -de una interfaz- el método *render()*, lo cual sería en esencia una *Vista*.